# Populating a CheckboxList

Tags: arrays, checkboxlist, populate

I have a Checkboxlist that is using a SqlDataSource. I am currently capturing data from the CheckboxList as follows:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < chkList.Items.Count; i++)
        {
        if (chkList.Items[i].Selected)
            {
                Items += chkList.Items[i].Value + ",";
            }
        }
        Items = Items.TrimEnd(',');
```

I then take this and insert it into a table as a string e.g. "111,222,333"

The question is how can I read this data back into the CheckboxList?

I'm currently at:

```
        string items = reader["Items"].ToString();
        string[] values = items.Split(',').Select(sValue => sValue.Trim()).ToArray();
        foreach (string values in value)
        {
            chkList.SelectedValue = reader[values].ToString();
        }
```

This works as to getting "111,222,333" but then how can I read this into the CheckboxList?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me!

```
chkList.DataBind();
string items = reader["Items"].ToString();
string[] values = items.Split(',').Select(sValue => sValue.Trim()).ToArray();
foreach (string value in values)
{
    ListItem liCheck = (ListItem)chkList.Items.FindByValue(value.ToString());
    if (liCheck != null)
        chkList.Items.FindByValue(value.ToString()).Selected = true;
 }
```

Comment: how are you getting data from database and binding to checkboxlist is it in `dataset` or `list`